# How to select some field in MongoDB using Pymongo?

Tags: python, pymongo

Currently I have a devices table with the following properties:
[image]

And i want to select userId, token, type field in this case with this code:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://this is my connection')

# Set database
db = client.test
devices = db.devices
cursor = devices.find({"userId": 1, "token": 1, "type": 1, "deviceId": 0, "_id" : 0})

result = []
for document in cursor:
    result.append(document)

print(result)

return {
    "data": result
}
```

But it haven't any response:

```
{"data": []}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

You forgot the query parameter in your find()
You have just put the filter parameter.

### Change in your code:

To find in all documents:

```py
cursor = devices.find({}, {"userId": 1, "token": 1, "type": 1, "deviceId": 0, "_id" : 0})
```

To find in a specific document:

```py
cursor = devices.find({"file": "your_specific_file_identifier"}, {"userId": 1, "token": 1, "type": 1, "deviceId": 0, "_id" : 0})
```

[MongoDB find() specifying filter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#specify-the-fields-to-return)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the find method incorrectly.

```
import pymongo

# Connect to MongoDB
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://your_connection_string')

# Set database and collection
db = client.test
devices = db.devices

# Define a projection to select the desired fields
projection = {"userId": 1, "token": 1, "type": 1, "_id": 0}

# Use the projection in the find method
cursor = devices.find({"userId": 1}, projection)

# Initialize a list to store the results
result = []

# Iterate through the cursor and append documents to the result list
for document in cursor:
    result.append(document)

print(result)

# Return the result
return {
    "data": result
}
```